# Roast almond for desserts

Tags: cake, dessert, almonds

I want to bake a cake that mimics the Sahne Nuss chocolate bar from Nestle. So my plan is a chocolate cake filled with a chocolate ganache with pieces of almond in it.

My question is: should I roast the almonds before adding into the ganache? I'm looking for a crunchy texture for the almonds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, roast the almonds. Be careful not to burn them. You can roast them in a dry skillet, tossing them frequently until aromatic and slightly darkened, or in the oven for maybe 25 minutes at 200°F (95°C).

Comment: This is a good answer. Flaked almonds are readily available and could also be used. The roasting time would be reduced to at most 5 minutes.

Comment: I assume you mean Fahrenheit, but could you clarify that in your answer to avoid the risk of unwary Celsius users singeing their bits?

Comment: I am surprised by the edit. My experience and online recipes, e.g. https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/roastedalmonds_70353, https://www.wikihow.com/Roast-Raw-Almonds all suggest that 200°C is about right. I think 95°C is far too low: this won't even toast bread!

Comment: Roasting for a shorter time at a higher temperature is possible, but it leads to the formation of acrylamide. Here is an article which explains this for more info. https://www.almonds.com/sites/default/files/content/attachments/aq0104_acrylamide_in_roasted_almonds.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. I'm still surprised 95°C is hot enough to roast the almonds, rather than just warm them through. Still, the linked article does say that acrylamide forms at 120°C.